# Why my function is not populating my dataframe column?

Tags: pandas

When my column['shipping'] is blank, I want to replace it with the current month(i.e September) if status = 70 and "hold' if the status is below 70.

But when I execute the function i get the following: array([None], dtype=object).

Here is my function:

```
def loaded(row):
  status = row['Ptkt Status']
  shipping = row['shipping']
 
  if status == 70:
   if shipping == '':
    current_month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%B')
    return current_month
  elif status < 70:
   if shipping == '':
   return "Hold"
 
 df['shipping'] = df.apply(loaded, axis=1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `m = df['shipping'].eq('') ; df.loc[m, 'shipping'] = np.select([df.loc[m, 'Ptkt Status'].eq(70), df.loc[m, 'Ptkt Status'].lt(70)], [datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%B'), 'Hold'], 'other']`